# Converting a Shape to a Bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3

I have created a subclass of `Shape` that contains paired `GraphicsPath` and `GraphicsStroke` objects. The class has a public method for retrieving the shape as a bitmap for passage to a Pixelbender kernel - the method is as follows:

```
public function GetBitmap():Bitmap{
    var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(this.width, this.height, true, 0x00FFFFFF);
    bmpData.draw(this);
    return new Bitmap(bmpData);
}
```

To test these, I have the following code:

```
var v:Vector.<Number> = new <Number>[10,10,50,10,50,50]; //defines GraphicsPath.data to be used
var wave:CustomWave = new CustomWave(v,0xff0000); //constructor for the subclass
wave.Refresh(); //clears the Shape and redraws the GraphicsPath 

//adds as shape
addChild(wave);

//adds as bitmap
var bmp:Bitmap = wave.GetBitmap()
addChild(bmp);
```

The visual output from both:

[image: Shape vs Bitmap output]

Any idea what could be causing the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a long story, how to work with `width` and `height`, if you don't want any problems, draw your path from (0,0) or you can modify your function:

```
public function GetBitmap():Bitmap {
    var bounds: Rectangle = getBounds(this);
    var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(bounds.width, bounds.height, true, 0);
    bmpData.draw(this, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -bounds.x, -bounds.y));
    return new Bitmap(bmpData);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work COMPLETELY the way I want, but gets me a hell of a lot closer. Thank you! Any chance you can explain what happened with the original code, or direct me to something that explains it?

Comment: Briefly speaking, `width/height` don't count that you draw your path from the (10,10) point, and give you result as 50. And after you created Bitmapdata with `width/height` equal to 50, It crops path. Example: if you draw square 10 px wide, at 200, `width` will return 10, not 210.

Comment: Well put... the rightmost 10 pixels are cut off, and that's why i only see a horizontal line that's slightly shorter than expected. I think I've got it - getBounds finds the center of the pixel on the far upper left corner on the bounding rectangle, and the matrix ensures the shape is repositioned to fit within a bitmap of the assigned width and height?

Comment: Yep! Definitely got it. See my edit to your answer. You've just given me a LOT of headway in understanding the way Flash processes coordinates - THANK YOU!

Comment: Yes, I have used identity Matrix with offset. Personally, I prefer do stuff from the 0,0 point, so fast getters `width` and `height` will be sufficient.

Comment: For the purposes I have planned, I'm not sure that starting from 0,0 will be sufficient - eventually I plan to create functions that calculate the x,y coordinates of each point using a parametric equation of the point's index in the data vector. Maybe I'll figure something out during optimization :)

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with the registration point of the `Shape` you're drawing into the `Bitmap`. Any chance you draw stuff above or to the left of the `0,0` coordinates? Then you'd have to add some params (perhaps a transformation Matrix) to the `draw` call, to get the right offset and such.

Comment: The paired GraphicsPath is the only object that is drawn on the Shape. GraphicsPath.Data is initialized to the first argument of the constructor (v in this code sample), so the coordinates of the path [(10,10), (50,10), (50,50)] should all be in the proper quadrant, unless I'm mistaken about how bmpData.draw(this) would draw into the Bitmap.

Comment: When a shape is created, I assume it uses 0,0 as the upper-left corner and matches the height and width to the contained drawing. I'm assuming that when addChild is called, it will grab the Shape as-is, and place it with the upper-left corner at 0,0. This matches my results in the 'FROM SHAPE' picture. Perhaps drawing to a bitmap works differently?